# How to add radio button

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, radio-button

Good morning everyone !

I have a problem with radio buttons in Laravel5 , now I receive an array of radio buttons called location1, location2, location3 correctly.

```
$inputLoc= $request->input('location1');
var_dump($inputLoc);
```

In this case I can show 0 or 1 depending to the selected value, but now I need to use this location here.

```
for ($i=0; $i <$numbers; $i++) { 
     $extra= new Extra();
     $extra->description=$informacion[$i];
     $extra->pi_id=$pi[$i];
     $extra->location=0;
     $extra->save();
}
```

How can I send the array of location into this for ? Could anyone help to me.

In the database I have a number 0 or 1 but I receive an String **string(1) "0"**

A lot of thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could use `'location'.$i` and make a test if it equal to "1" or "0" :

```
for ($i=0; $i <$numbers; $i++) { 
   $extra= new Extra();
   $extra->description=$informacion[$i];
   $extra->pi_id=$pi[$i];
   $extra->location=$request->input('location'.$i)=="1"?1:0;
   $extra->save();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is an integer 0 or 1

Comment: what is the output of var_dump($inputLoc);

Comment: I receive an string

Comment: The aim problem is receive location1 , location2 , location3 ... in the for correctly , if i solved this part I can continue.

Comment: Emm i think you need `$request->input('location'.$i);` is that it?

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'location' cannot be null  , I don't know which is the problem.

Comment: Try to use `dd($request->input('location'.$i));` to make sure that you recieve correct value.